# Are DB2 user-defined functions cached somewhere, even if dropped and created again..?

Tags: db2, db2-400

I'm working on an old AS/400 DB2 system with v6r1m0, and Navigator v7r1m0 on Windows 7x64.

Today I created my first UDF on this system, but quickly realized something isn't working as expected. If I drop the function, make a change, and then create it again...the returned value doesn't change. It's as if there's compiled code that's cached/mirrored/saved somewhere...even if dropped.

After the drop/change/create, if I go to the schema tree in Navigator and Generate the SQL of the function, I **do** see the new changes. But the value returned by the function is that from the **previous** version of the SQL.

Consider the following lines of SQL, all created & run in the Navigator SQL window. When this is run, two result tabs are opened, but the returned value in both windows is the **same**. Both results are 'Y'; the 'N' never appears.

What's going on here?  Is there a problem with this server/db/connection/etc, or (more likely) is there some some basic principle at play that I'm unaware of...?

```
CREATE FUNCTION CERTODB.TESTME 
    () 
    RETURNS VARCHAR(1)

    LANGUAGE SQL 
    DETERMINISTIC 
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 

    BEGIN  

    RETURN 'Y'  ;  -- CHANGES BELOW

    END  ;

SELECT CERTODB.TESTME() FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 ; -- RETURNS 'Y'

DROP FUNCTION CERTODB.TESTME ;

CREATE FUNCTION CERTODB.TESTME 
    () 
    RETURNS VARCHAR(1)

    LANGUAGE SQL 
    DETERMINISTIC 
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 

    BEGIN  

    RETURN 'N'  ;  -- VALUE HAS BEEN CHANGED  

    END  ;

SELECT CERTODB.TESTME() FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 ; -- STILL RETURNS 'Y'..!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me...but I'm running v7.2...

I don't recall any issues using UDFs on 6.1...

IBM i is object based, so your two functions are seen as two separate objects each with a unique address.  And it does support "replace while in use" but that's normally seen in HLL programs compiled with REPLACE(*YES).

You might try disconnecting and reconnecting between calls.

Comment: Could be that you are coming up against 'lazy close' and that the old version is still in use from a connection that's been around longer than you think. (Replaced compiled objects, which UDFs are under the covers, stay on the system and get cleared out at, as I recall, the next IPL.) I'd try it from STRSQL to see what you get there.

Comment: Is it possible to force immediate housekeeping, or go digging wherever the compiled objects are and kill it there..? When does IPL occur..? This system is scheduled to reboot once a week. Thanks for the tip on the STRSQL; I'll see if that helps.

Comment: Well that didn't go very far. I tried to run STRSQL, but it's not installed. It displays this message: "DB2 Query Manager and SQL Development Kit for i5/OS not available.".

Comment: That's a shame. If you are in a position to end and restart the database host server (ENDHOSTSVR *DATABASE / STRHOSTSVR *DATABASE) you could try that (N.B. you may have a lot of live clients using it!) P.S. IPL = Initial Program Load = reboot.

Comment: I had several time this sort of "cached UDF effect"... I have no clear answer but, for me on V7R1 , stopping all jobs that had an access to this UDF did the trick